# Why does it say that app.firestore is not a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

```
import * as firebase from "firebase/app";
import 'firebase/firestore'

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "api key",
    authDomain: "asdjfg.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "aksdjgh.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "test-asdkjkgfsg",
    storageBucket: "tasdgaest-asdfg-asgafg.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "asgas5554",
    appId: "1:asgasdgasgef76b"
};

const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const db = app.firestore();
export default db
```

Why does it say that app.firestore is not a function?

I have installed firebase & firebase-tools

Comment: No, I saw that but that didnt solve my problem

Comment: The previous one marked by @AnuragSrivastava works for V8. If you have `v9.0.0+` installed check this one ^

Comment: Thanks a lot @Dharmaraj, I don't know what to say. I have been stuck with this problem for 2 days, and Now I got it! 